# Is a convex cone a convex polyhedron?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polyhedra, convex-geometry

Say that I have a convex cone

$C=\{t|Ax = t, x\geq 0\}$.

where $x\in R^n$, and $t\in R^m$, $A\in R^m\times R^n$.

Can I say that this is a convex polyhedron? and why?

**EDIT**:
Just in order to avoid confusion, the definition of convex polyhedron I am thinking of is: *the set of solutions to a finite number of linear equalities and inequalites*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or more precisely (as *polyhedron* may imply three dimensions) a convex *polytope*. You may readily verify that $C$ is convex, and also that its boundary is piecewise a part of a hyperplane.

Comment: But if its boundary is intersection of infinite hyperplane then it is not a convex polyhedron right?

Answer (score -1):

No.  A cone is **not** a "polyhedron".  A polyhedron, by definition has planar (straight) sides, not curved sides.

Comment: Incidentally, the set in the question is the linear image of an octant, so does have straight faces

Comment: a cone does not necessarily have curved sides. Surely not every cone is polyhedral. But that one in OP is...

Comment: @user251257 Why do you say the convex cone I wrote is polyhedral?